# Would a camless engine need a starter motor?

Tags: engine-theory

In theory, if you had a working camless engine with fully variable valves... Would it be possible to just have the engine start itself by choosing the most appropriately placed cylinder at the time and give it fuel/spark (with direct injection), while opening the exhaust valves on the other cylinders, then repeat for the others? Could it work?

Comment: the presumption is one cylinder is sitting there retaining its charge pressure from the last time it was run?  Pretty far fetched.

Comment: I think you answered your own question :) 
Also, here's a patent on this https://www.google.com/patents/US20060016413

Comment: @agentp . For start - stop situations, not really far fetched.

Comment: ok I can see that if we are just shutting down for a minute, restarting while still hot.

Comment: @agentp I don't think you need the charge pressure. Just inject fuel and ignite it, and you then have pressure. Of course this is less optimal than having the charge pressure, but it may be enough to just start the engine. Doesn't work for diesels, though, as they don't have a spark plug.

Comment: you will not get enough energy ( or even get the fuel to ignite) without adequate pressure and temperature.

Comment: I say we move back to hand cranks on the front of the car.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Ahh hand cranks or starting handles : just make sure your thumb is the same side of the handle as your fingers and don't bend your wrist...

Comment: @chilljeet - Answer the question ... you nailed it with your patent search.

Comment: mildly related. an engine being camless doesn't negate the need for a starter, it just makes it possible (like the referenced patent). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3cFfM3r510